# Simple server: bash + ncat

Tags: bash

I want to write a very simple server emulator.
A client is a box with ESP8266 (AT commands).
A server is a set of bash scripts.
The server's responses depend on client's requests.
I use ncat and bash.

I have a strange behaviour.
When I use INDATA=`cat /dev/stdin`, stdout does not work (ESP8266 does not receive any data)!
And vice versa.
When I do not use INDATA=`cat /dev/stdin`, stdout works!
It is only when I use srvemu1.sh.
When I run srvemu2.sh by my hands it works!
I think that something wrong with ncat usage... what is wrong?

**srvemu1.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
    ncat -lv 8080 -e "....../srvemu2.sh"
done
```

**srvemu2.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 1

INDATA=`cat /dev/stdin`
if [ ! -z $(echo "$INDATA" | grep '123' -o) ]
then
    echo 123
else
    echo 456
fi
```

Comment: How do you call `srvemu2.sh`? What is its input? `cat` will block until stdin is closed. That could be the reason why you don't see any output.

Comment: srvemu2.sh is run with ncat in srvemu1.sh. It is only so... `echo 123 | ./srvemu2.sh` works fine :) The server starts when I run srvemu1.sh. If cat blocks why does it work when I run srvemu2.sh by my hands?

Comment: Do I read input data wrong?

Comment: @koluna, run it by hand _and do what_? How do you close stdin? `echo 123 | ...` implicitly closes `echo`'s stdout / `...`'s stdin when `echo` completes, but if you're feeding ncat in without the remote server closing the outbound side of the connection...

Comment: Anyhow -- how much data do you need? If you only need one line, stop using `cat` in favor of `IFS= read -r INDATA` (but don't use `INDATA` as a variable name -- all-caps variables are in reserved space; applications should use names with at least one lowercase character for their own variables).

Comment: @koluna, ...to simulate the problem you have, instead of using `echo 123 | ./srvemu2.sh`, just run `./srvemu2.sh` directly in your shell, type `123`, press enter... and you'll see it hang, just like your real code.

Comment: pluse-uno as you have code  and an interesting problem. Did you look at the other 75 Q/A when you search here for `[bash] ncat` ? Good luck.

Comment: I need 500-1000 bytes. It are some strings. I must find out key substrings and answer to the client. How should I read data from ncat's stdout when it run script?

Comment: It does not work too with 
`while read LINE
do
 INDATA+="$LINE"
done < /dev/stdin`
What can I do? What should I read about?